# Connect to MongoDB Atlas while i am behind college proxy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, networking, proxy, mern

I have a MERN application in my system that used to work perfectly, now i am behind my college proxy , so I changed node proxy using

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port
```

And in mongo atlas i have allowed all IP addresses to connect.

```
0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address)
```

still while running the apllication i am getting this error from mongoDB side.

```
const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                               ^
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
```

I also tried to connect using mongosh and MongoDB compass any of these didn't connect to the atlas.

someone help me, please.